# RSpec not allowing pending methods

Tags: ruby, rspec

When I try and define (but not implement an it test) (pending method) using RSpec

```
describe "test" do
  it "should not fail, but does"
end
```

I get this error when I try and run

```
ArgumentError in 'should not fail, but does'
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

Does anyone know why this is happening? Am I doing something wrong? (I am using Ruby 1.9.2 and RSpec 1.3.0). Can somebody please help me fix this problem?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't line up with the error you posted. If the problem was with that pending example the error would say "ArgumentError in 'test should not fail, but does'" - check your code where you define "should not be doing this".

Comment: Thanks that was a typo on my part.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wow, weird. I was able to duplicate your problem with Ruby 1.9.2. No idea why it happens, but this lets you have a properly pending spec:

```
class Foo
end

describe Foo do
  # This fails in Ruby 1.9.2 but works in 1.8.7
  it "is pending"

  # This works in both
  it "is pending" do
    pending
  end
end
```

rspec 2.0.0 seems to fix the issue with 1.9.2, however.

Answer (score 1):

it's a bug in rspec 1.3.0 I believe, under 1.9.2 http://www.google.com/search?q=rspec+wrong+number+of+arguments+%281+for+0%29&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-SearchBox&ie=&oe=#sclient=psy&hl=en&rls=com.microsoft%3Aen-us%3AIE-SearchBox&q=rspec+%22wrong+number+of+arguments+(1+for+0)%22&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=f82d49f7a278c83c&cad=b